# When filling a form at document_end my script clicks a button which reloads the page so it runs again. How do I stop it running?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest, infinite-loop

I´m writing a small program to autofill fields with a script.

It then submits the form.

However, once the form is submitted it reloads the page and the script runs again.

Hence, it is adding the user an infinite amount of times.

Ideally I want to add a user fill diferent information and add the next for up to 100 user.

I´m not sure how to stop this infinite loop, Im assuming the script also restarts when the page resets.

I

I tried placing a function that runs my script but since my script is run when the page loads, even though the function is in a for loop it runs non stop.

Its also hard to test since infinite loops are an issue you cant really get out of without it running to many times in first place.

My Manifest code is the following:

```
{
    "name": "Begginer",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Fill",

//    "permissions": [
//        "activeTab",
//        "*://*/*"
//    ],    

    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": ["website"],
        "run_at": "document_end",   
        "js": ["Fill.js"]
        }
    ],

    "icons":
    {
    "16": "images/puppy16.png", 
    "48": "images/puppy48.png",
    "128": "images/puppy128.png"
    },

    "browser_action":
    {
    "default_icon": "images/puppy128.png"
    }

}
```

My JS:

```
    // define your username and password
    var Nam='Oi Macaco';
    var Gen='M';
    var Nbi='123';
    var Ser='Servico';
    var Dna='01-01-2000';
    var Dab='01-01-2000';
    var Cat='categorai';
    var Dis='Lunda';
    var Ema='email@domain.com';
    var Npa='123';
    var Una='OMacaco';

    // Finds Each Field
    var NameF   = document.getElementById('nome_new');
    var SexoF   = document.getElementById('sexo_new');
    var NbiF    = document.getElementById('num_bi');
    var SerF    = document.getElementById('servico');
    var DnfF    = document.getElementById('data_nasc_func');
    var DadF    = document.getElementById('data_admissao');
    var CatF    = document.getElementById('categoria');
    var DisF    = document.getElementById('distrito');
    var EmaF    = document.getElementById('email_new');
    var PasF    = document.getElementById('password_new');
    var UnaF    = document.getElementById('unamesso_new');

    // Fills the Fields
    NameF.value     = Nam;
    SexoF.value = Gen;
    NbiF.value  = Nbi;
    SerF.value  = Ser;
    DnfF.value  = Dna;
    DadF.value  = Dab;
    CatF.value  = Cat;
    DisF.value  = Dis;
    EmaF.value  = Ema;
    PasF.value  = Npa;
    UnaF.value  = Una;

    //Click Button
    document.getElementById('Button1').click();
```

Everything is working, the problem is it runs an infinite number of times.

So I assume I can´t even add the Next User.

Everything is an assumption since its hard to test infinite loops, I wasnt really expecting it.

I think I should use chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback)

Then I should make a function that has a switch for every different user.

But that does not seem like the best way.

Help. Thx.

Comment: Don't use content_scripts in manifest, but instead use chrome.tabs.executeScript in your popup script or background script so you can control what happens.

Comment: Thank you, I understand

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by inserting the following code:

Thanks to DanHarper,

Manifest

```
{
  "name": "Inject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Injecting stuff",

  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Inject!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

Inject.js

```
(function() {

    // define your username and password
    var Nam='Oi Macaco';
    var Gen='M';
    var Nbi='123';
    var Ser='Servico';
    var Dna='01-01-2000';
    var Dab='01-01-2000';
    var Cat='categorai';
    var Dis='Lunda';
    var Ema='email@somethin';
    var Npa='123';
    var Una='OMacaco';

    // Finds Each Field
    var NameF   = document.getElementById('nome_new');
    var SexoF   = document.getElementById('sexo_new');
    var NbiF    = document.getElementById('num_bi');
    var SerF    = document.getElementById('servico');
    var DnfF    = document.getElementById('data_nasc_func');
    var DadF    = document.getElementById('data_admissao');
    var CatF    = document.getElementById('categoria');
    var DisF    = document.getElementById('distrito');
    var EmaF    = document.getElementById('email_new');
    var PasF    = document.getElementById('password_new');
    var UnaF    = document.getElementById('unamesso_new');

    // Fills the Fields
    NameF.value     = Nam;
    SexoF.value = Gen;
    NbiF.value  = Nbi;
    SerF.value  = Ser;
    DnfF.value  = Dna;
    DadF.value  = Dab;
    CatF.value  = Cat;
    DisF.value  = Dis;
    EmaF.value  = Ema;
    PasF.value  = Npa;
    UnaF.value  = Una;

    //Click Button
    document.getElementById('Button1').click();

    alert('inserted self... giggity');

})();
```

Background code:

```
// listen for our browserAction to be clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    });
});
```